# Create quantity invetory with multiple stock_ids in magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap

I have two stock_ids (1,3) in cataloginventory_stock_item table for product admin inventory quantity fields,
While iam creating the product using apis, i wants to create product by multiple stockids for different quantity value fields, in magento1.9

for single stock iam creating by below code:

```
$stockItemData = array('manage_stock ' => 1,
    'use_config_manage_stock' => 1, 
    'stock_id' =>  1,
    'qty' => 5,
    'is_in_stock ' => 1


);
```

In the above code need to pass multiple stockid for creating product through soap api.

Thanks

Comment: The core API does not provide this feature. We would need to know which extension you are using for this multi-warehouse feature?

Comment: it's generating while creating add specific store only, it's getting from wholesale folio theme

Comment: I need to pass both values while creating product from soap api

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the Magento documentation, the core API does not support updating the `stock_id` attribute:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalogInventory/cataloginventory_stock_item.update.html

In order to update multiple `stock_id` from the same SOAP call, you will have to create your own API function, as documented here:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/create_your_own_api.html

Usually, the extension that provides the multi-warehouse functionality offers its own API to work with various `stock_id`

Comment: Hi Olivier's thanks for your support I have different stock IDs but I wants to update the qty values of those stock ids

Comment: @shivashankarm Yeah, this is not possible with the core SOAP API, it always only updates stock_id = 1. In order to do what you want, you need to code it or look for a third-party extension.